# What do the parentheses mean when you're declaring/calling a property?

Tags: javascript

**Example 1**:

```
function a(){
  return "ok";
}

function b(){
  this.c = a;
}

var d = new b();
alert(d.c()); // Result "ok".
```

**Example 2**:

```
function b(){
    this.c = a();
}

var d = new b();
alert(d.c); // Result "ok".
```

What do the parentheses mean in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `()` after a function *calls* it - causing the function to be executed. In your examples, the function is `a`.

Your two cases can be thought of as:

**Example 1**

```
d.c = a;
d.c(); // Call function a
```

**Example 2**

```
d.c = a(); // Call function a, put result in d.c
d.c;
```

In either case the function `a` is being called with `()` exactly once - hence they produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

First case:

```
this.c=a;
```

This sets the `c` property of the object (that `b` is called on) to a reference to the *function* `a`.

Any function can be called (even via a reference) using the `()` syntax, which is what `alert(d.c())` does.

Second case:

```
this.c=a();
```

This *calls `a`*, and sets `c` to the result (i.e. return value) of `a`, which is the string "ok".

Then, retrieving the value of `c` with `alert(d.c)` will yield the same result as your first example, but it is arrived at in fundamentally different ways.

One way stores a reference to the function itself, and calls it when its value is needed, while the other calls the function right away and stores only the result for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, with `this.c = a` you are setting `this.c` with the "pointer" to a function, which you then call with `d.c()`.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's enough right answers here, I'll show an interesting consequence:

```
var counter = 1

function a() {
  return counter++
}

function b() {
  this.c = a;    // your example 1
  this.e = a();  // your example 2
}

var d = new b();

//a() was evaluated once, result put in e
alert(d.e);         // 1
alert(d.e);         // 1
alert(d.e);         // 1

//a() is evaluated each call:
alert(d.c());       // 2
alert(d.c());       // 3
alert(d.c());       // 4
```

Comment: interesting... so there's a difference